# Make manga.stackexchange.com redirect to anime.stackexchange.com

Tags: feature-request

It would make sense to have http://manga.stackexchange.com redirect to http://anime.stackexchange.com.

The site *is* Anime **& Manga** after all.

Comment: Eh, I dunno... I guess it wouldn't do any harm, but it's also pretty unnecessary - the only people who would benefit from this would be people who type `http://manga.stackexchange.com/` into their browsers. (Contrast the case of `math.SE` vs. `maths.SE`, which is legitimately useful b/c Brits will often type the latter.)

Comment: I agree that while this wouldn't hurt anything, it also seems unnecessary. For comparison, `http://cardgames.stackexchange.com/` doesn't redirect to http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/, even though their top 3 tags are actually card games and not board games. Nor does `http://tv.stackexchange.com/` take you to http://movies.stackexchange.com/ (but, FWIW, http://fantasy.stackexchange.com does redirect). Unless there's some demonstrable use for the redirect, this is pretty low on my list of features we need.

Comment: Actually I think otaku.stackexchange.com would have been better than anime.stackexchange.com since it means people obssesed or who share an interest in both anime and manga,

Comment: But otherwise I guess the redirect might be useful. But I don't see much use in it though.

Comment: @LoganM Well, I'm not sure the omittance of it for other sites is a strong case for omitting it here, too, especially when we don't know if it's really due to genuine reluctance for valid reasons or just due to being forgotten in those cases. Afterall, it works for [scifi.se], [unix.se] and [gardening.se], too.

Answer (score 7):

This wouldn't *hurt* anything, because I doubt that we'd ever have a manga.SE that *wasn't* this site, but I'm not certain that it would really help anything?

There's no SEO value, since the redirect is going to be to anime - so making links with it won't really do anything. Anime is just as easy to type as manga, so there's no real shortcut value there (a good example is expats => expatriates).

Is there a more strategic reason to have it? E.g. flyers or other promotional things directed at people purely into manga, where having that specific URL would be like some extra special sauce? We'd need something to justify bugging one of the devs to set this up, beyond the sake of simply having it - did I miss another use case?

Comment: Actually, it was something raised in our [survey](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/968/the-anime-manga-quarterly-feedback-survey?cb=1) and we figured it's a good idea. I don't see a concrete reason for it **right now**, but as you said, it won't hurt, and there might be a reason for it in the future. We're planning all sorts of things, and who knows where it'll lead us.

Comment: I'm not _against_ it, I'm just trying to figure out how to ask them to do it :)

Answer (score 7):

Yes, this should happen.

There's already precedent for doing this for ***&*** sites that deal with two simultaneous names and topics:

- Linux & Unix: https://unix.stackexchange.com/ and https://unix.stackexchange.com/
- Gardening & Landscaping: https://gardening.stackexchange.com/ and https://gardening.stackexchange.com/
- Science Fiction & Fantasy: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/ and https://scifi.stackexchange.com/
- [Movies & TV just received a request for a similar redirect](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2625/can-should-tv-stackexchange-com-redirect-to-this-site) (movies.se and tv.se) which is my impetus for leaving this response.

Anime & Manga Stack Exchange is in this same family, and should similarly have both https://anime.stackexchange.com/ and http://manga.stackexchange.com/, so that a person visiting this site by either name finds it.